# In how many ways they can arrange given the following conditions?

Tags: permutations, combinations

> A pizza shop made pizzas with many flavours. There are 9 different flavours, in that 2 flavours are taken to make pizza. In how many ways they can arrange?

a)$36$

b)$16$

c)$26$

d)$46$

**MyApproach**

According to me,Ans is $72$ i.e $9$p$2$.Because they said arrangement.So,Out of $9$ different pizzas I can arrange  $2$ flavours.

Comment: I have doubt its said arrange but arrange what pizzas or toppings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer you have given is partially right its $9C2$. But still the doubt is arrangement of pizza or the toppings.

Comment: If it was topping then Ans would be $9$C$2$?

Comment: @justintakro: Yep!

Comment: I hope you know the difference betn arrangement of pizzas and toppings.

Comment: @Archis welankar Why  9P2/2 ?

Comment: @justintakro $9$P$2$ =$\binom9{2}2!$. So I guess he meant just don't multiply in the $2!$

Comment: We know that combination is selection of n things taken m at a time. So isnt it taking out 2 elements from 9 so its more like $9P2/2$=$9C2$.

Comment: But for pizza its $9P2$ only because we are not selecting a pizza we are selecting a topping for a pizza

Comment: @ArchisWelankar Yes,you are right we can select either topping or full  pizza.But Why you divided by 2?

Comment: @justin takro I did $9C2$ basically . See the definition of combinations as pizza toppings are combinations not permutations .

Answer (score 1):

If you take 2 out of 9 elements you have $ {9 \choose 2} = {9! \over {2!7!}}=36 $

Comment: How you arranged?

Answer (score 0):

The in process of making a pizza you *select* two of the nine flavours and then *arrange* them on the pizza base - but *how*?   Does the *order* you arrange the flavours on the pizza make a difference?   Is a ham and pineapple pizza somehow *distinct* from a pineapple and ham pizza?

There are ${^{9}\mathrm C_{2}}$ ways to select the flavours.   If it makes a difference, there are $2!$ ways to arrange them - but *does* it?

So there are ${^{9}\mathrm C_{2}}$ options when order of selection does not matter, and ${^{9}\mathrm P_{2}}$ options when the order of selection results in different pizza types.

Make a choice. Hmm $36$ or $72$? ... Let's look at the menu again...